# "A variable of type"

Tags: grammar, articles

In programming every datum has some type. For example:

> 1, 2, 3, are of int type
>
> 'a', 'b', 'c' are of char type
>
> '5/17/2019' is of Date type

I often see phrases like this one:

> A variable of type char

Why is there no article before "type"?

Comment: This particular construction is brilliantly covered [***here***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133192/why-use-be-of-something-is-there-some-meaning-for-this-of) on ELU. Briefly, both the indefinite article *(**a**)* and preposition *(**of**)* can be discarded in *some* contexts like those above (also note that idiomatically, we usually say *Param1 is **of type char***, not ***...of char type***). But not in *all* contexts - ***of*** is required *I'm writing a function that expects a parameter **of type unknown***, for example.

Comment: ...including the article (as in *This parameter must be of **a** Date type*) tends to imply there are *multiple* "Date type" storage formats - which exact "subtype" the parameter has to be is either unspecified OR irrelevant (because ***any*** of those Date subtypes is acceptable for this parameter).

Comment: I think the article being omitted, here, is actually "the", not "a". But that linked question answers it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, but the linked question doesn't say anything about articles, does it? It says only about omitting "of"... Could you please explain what  did you mean?

Comment: The answer to that earlier question specifically gives two different example contexts - one for the indefinite article *(It expects the parameter to be of **a** type not yet defined)* and one for the definite article *(It expects the parameter to be of **the** type we encountered in section 3.4)*. And discussing the formal syntactic constraints, StoneyB specifically says *You need **of** and a **determiner***. Usually that "determiner" will be a definite or indefinite article, but in certain contexts other determiners *(**our, this**, etc.)* could also be used,

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there no article before "type"?

You're not really talking about a type, you are talking about a variable.  *Variable* already has an article.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is just placing mistake, it should be "a variable of char type" meaning that the variable type (data type) is CHAR

You can see this link as reference http://cis.poly.edu/~mleung/CS1114/s09/ch02/char.htm